# Adding a billing method with google cloud results in "unexpected error"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I've been trying to add a billing method to my google compute engine without any luck. After inserting my Visa card details and clicking the submit button, I always get the following message:

An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later.

I am trying to create a google compute engine instance, but without billing enabled, this is not possible. I already tried contact google cloud billing support by filling out the online support form. However, it says responses usually take 2 to 3 business days. Now, is the problem I am facing limited to my account or is everybody else facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got fixed several hours after I posted my question. It seems that the problem was from google's end.

Comment: Did that problem appeared again? Meanwhile i'm facing this problem everymonth. I have to repair payment method (just click chekcbox) and then payment goes through. I've called my bank and they toldme that VISA somehow blocks this transactions, but do not provides any details. I've contakted GCE support via email. And they where not aware of anything. I don't like this bool shit.. Visa and google are both huge companies. So visa paymens should just work :( Don't have any solution now.