# Google Cloud services "enable billing" error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, error-code, google-cloud-billing

I just created a Google Cloud Platform account and wanted to start a Compute Engine project. When I tried it asked me to set up my billing info. I put in all my information and pressed "submit and enable billing", but recieved an error:

"An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR-CBAT-05]"

I tried looking it up but i could not find what the error code is for, google directed me to stackoverflow for an answer so now I'm here. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: I *just* got the same thing

Comment: It may just resolve in time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460687/adding-a-billing-method-with-google-cloud-results-in-unexpected-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be due to a suspended billing account. I had an email saying I needed to provide more verification. After that process was finalised I was able to enable billing successfully.

Comment: yes i just received an email saying my account has been suspended, bummer lol. Thank you for your time.

Comment: faced the same issue, but had to go through a 48-hour waiting period because of a bug in their verification process. Lesson learnt - set up billing at least 48 hours before it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Look for Google Cloud Platform console help.

then
Verify payment information to continue..

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/verify?contact_type=verify&cloud_account_id..